# How to declare a matrix that is stored in PROGMEM

Tags: c, avr, atmega16, codevisionavr

I am trying to write a header file that will drive a LED Matrix but I'm stuck with a syntax error which I cannot resolve

I've already added " ; " everywhere I thought it was necessary and checked https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html

```
#ifndef max7219_H_
#define max7219_H_

#include <io.h>
#include <pgmspace.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SLAVE_SELECT PORTB &= ~( 1<<PB4 );     
#define SLAVE_DESELECT PORTB |= ~( 1<<PB4 ); 

char characters[96][5] PROGMEM = 
{ 
   {
    0b00000000,
    0b00000000,
    0b00000000,
    0b00000000,
    0b00000000 
    }  
};
```

ERROR IS : Error: max7219.h(15), #included from: p2.c: ';' expected

line 15 is  char characters[96][5] PROGMEM = ...

Comment: Can you change `0b00000000` to `0` and try?

Comment: `char characters[96][5] PROGMEM` is invalid. Why add `PROGMEM`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie do you know AVR gcc port?

Comment: I see `<avr/pgmspace.h>` being used

Comment: BTW the previous macros perhaps shouldn't have the trailing `;`, otherwise it is easy to make mistakes with `if` without braces...

Comment: when I was finishing using AVRs I started to use named address spaces instead of progmem.  You should search for `__flash` `__memx` etc etc

Comment: If the array is made const, [I don't see any compile errors](https://godbolt.org/z/urGqjS). Are you sure this is your actual source file? Are you sure you don't have any other warnings, e.g. "unable to find `pgmspace.h`" or something? Perhaps you meant `avr/pgmspace.h`? If `PROGMEM` is not defined, then you would get a [similar error](https://godbolt.org/z/Uyi_Y9).

Comment: @Groo .. yes that was a cpoy - paste from the source code , and no for some reason CodeVision has no ideea what <avr/pgmspace.h> is but it knows it as <pgmspace.h> ... At the end I had succeded (?) in resolving the error i had to declare it as  `code` PROGMEM char characters[96][5] `/code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const PROGMEM uint8_t characters[96][5] = {
    {
      0b00000000,
      0b00000000,
      0b00000000,
      0b00000000,
      0b00000000 
   },
    ... // 95 more symbols
 };
```

Note, if an array declared with dimension, it should contain all the data in the initializer, i.e. all 96 symbols.

**UPD:** The error could be caused by the code in `pc2.c` just before `#include "max7219.h"`
If you have several "includes", then check the previous one. I.e:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "max7219.h"
```

the error may be at the end of `b.h`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it const to put in flash. Also i am guessing that you need to make two arrays.

Try:

```
     const char c1[] PROGMEM = "1";
     const char c2[] PROGMEM = "2";

     const char * const strings[] PROGMEM = {c1, c2};
```

Comment: That one did not work either , I think there something particular to the CodeVison AVR ... After some more fiddling I got rid of the error , the answer was to move PROGMEM at the start of the delaration like this : PROGMEM char characters[96][5]